# Jenkins java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Permission denied) при выполнении кода Groovy

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Создал проект в Jenkinse, который должен писать текст с переменными в файл
пробую писать текст в файл

```
out << main_text
```

или

```
out.text = main_text
```

Так же пробовал через

```
if(!out.exists()) {
    out.createNewFile()
    out << main_text
      }
```

На все попытки выдает

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: readme.txt (Permission denied)

Код предварительно проверил локально - все работает

Comment: Попробуйте запустить java от администратора либо в папке пользователя создавать файл

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipeline DSL (контекст) запускается всегда на мастере, даже если указать определенный агент `node('someAgentName')` в вашем пайплайне. Поэтому операции с классом `File` почти всегда бесполезны.

Для подобных случаев используйте Pipeline step [writeFile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-writefile-code-write-file-to-workspace) или [sh()](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script):

```
writeFile(file: 'readme.txt', text: main_text)
sh("echo '${main_text}' >> readme.txt)
```

Comment: Вот ни за что сам бы не догадался! Спасибо!

Comment: Значит дело в правах. Вы Jenkins user создавали? Какие права давали?

Comment: Прошу прощения. Не успел дописать, отвлекли. С записью в воркспейс все ок. Не пишет в стороннюю директорию /path/to/file/, ошибка та же

Comment: Тогда однозначно стоит проверить права пользователя. Пробовали `sudo echo '${main_text}' >> /path/to/file/`?